# Expectation of exponents of Random Matrices

Tags: probability, matrices, expected-value, random, matrix-exponential

**TLDR**: Given a random matrix A, how to find a closed form expression for a deterministic matrix B such that $\mathbb{E}[e^A]=e^B$, in terms of the elements of A?

**Background**: So this has to do with solutions of switching linear systems of the form $\dot{x}=Ax+Du$. The random matrix A doesn't have any special properties as far as I can tell, other than the fact that has a couple of zero eigenvalues (it is 9x9 for my use case). The D matrix is deterministic. Some of the entries in the matrix are random scalars; that is, they switch between two values randomly. The rest of the entries in the matrix A are deterministic.

I am interested in finding what the 'averaged' system looks like. So I need to find the deterministic system matrix B so that the system $\dot{y}=By+Du$ is the average of the random system: $\mathbb{E}[x]=y$. Here $x$ and $y$ are vectors.

I can find it numerically using Monte-Carlo type simulations (take a large number of realizations of matrix A, find $e^A$ for each, take the average and take the matrix logarithm to get B) but this won't give me an exact representation. So for example if the random elements in the A matrix are a,b,c, I want to find an expression for B in terms of (a,b,c).

Any thoughts or suggestions?

(Also, I'm not really a math student but a dumb engineer, so I have a feeling this is probably child's play to some math majors)

PS: I've added an example of the 9x9 A matrix to give a better idea:
Here, a, b, c are binomial random variables, can take the value {0,1} with known probabilities and are independent of each other. But, since some of these variables occur more than once, I cannot claim that all elements of the matrix A are independent of each other.

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0& & & & & &\\
    0&0&1 &&&&&&\\
    0&0&-1&&&&&&&\\
    &&&0&1&0&&&&\\
    &&&0&0&1&&&&\\
    1&1&a&-1&-2&-1&&&\\
    &&&&&&0&1&0&\\
    &&&&&&0&0&1&\\
   b&b&b&1&1&c&(-b-1)&(-2-3b)&-1
    \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: What is $D$ and $u$? In any case your ODE admits an analytic solution. The solution involves $e^{tA}$ but not only. Do you want the average of $e^{A}$ or the average of $x$? In any case you have to know the explicit form of $A$ and its random behavior.

Comment: @lcv: Well $u$ is just an input to the system and $D$ is another deterministic matrix. Yes, you are right, the solution involves $e^{tA}$. Since $t$ is just a scalar, I am focused on just the behaviour of $e^A$. I want the averaged system so I am interested in the system matrix (B) of the averaged system, for which I need the averaged $e^A$. Also yes, I know the explicit form of A (i.e, which of the elements are deterministic, and which of the elements are random). How do I use this information?

Comment: Everything depends on the explicit form of $A$. Can you give it? Especially the way randomness enters the game. You're kind of asking to compute an integral (this is what computing averages is in a sense) but you are not giving the function you have to integrate.

Comment: If some entries of $A$ are Gaussian, the average may be doable. Same for other simple distributions.. finding $B$ however is quite hard.

Comment: I've edited the post to clarify and give the A matrix; sorry I probably should've done that from the beginning. Also, the variables take the values {0,1} with known probabilities. So basically $\mathbb{E}[a], \mathbb{E}[b], \mathbb{E}[c]$ is known

Comment: I cooked an answer. Unfortunately I don't think it can be done. (If that is what you aim to)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $A$ and $Du$ are time independent. Then the differential equation

$$
\dot{x}(t) = A x(t) + Du
$$

has the following solution (found with the method of "variation of constants")

$$
x(t) = U(t) x(0) + \int_0^t ds U(t-s) Du
$$

where

$$
U(t) = e^{tA}
$$

satisfies the homogenous ODE:

$$\dot{U}(t) = A U(t).$$

Note that $U(t)$ satisfies the semi-group property $U(t+s)=U(t)U(s)$. Now, $A$ is a random matrix and it seems you are interested in the expectation value of $x(t)$, i.e. $y(t):=\mathsf{E}[x(t)]$.

Defining $$\mathcal{E}(t):=\mathsf{E}[U(t)],$$ we have

$$
y(t) = \mathcal{E}(t) x(0) + \int_0^t ds \mathcal{E}(t-s) Du \tag{1}
$$

Next it seems that you are interested in finding an ODE for $y(t)$. I don't think that this may be possible. Indeed, we would proceed in the following way:

Define
$$
B(t) : = \dot{\mathcal{E}}(t) \mathcal{E}^{-1}(t)
$$

so $\mathcal{E}(t)$ satisfies

$$
\dot{\mathcal{E}}(t)  = B(t) \mathcal{E}(t)
$$

and we would hope that $y(t)$ satisfied:

$$
\dot{y}(t) = B(t) y(t) + Du \tag{2}
$$

Unfortunately, the solution of (2) is

$$
y(t) = \mathcal{E}(t) x(0) + \int_0^t ds \mathcal{E}(t) \mathcal{E}^{-1}(s) Du
$$

But this is different from Eq. (1) because $\mathcal{E}(t) \mathcal{E}^{-1}(s)\neq \mathcal{E}(t-s)$ unless $B(t)$ is time independent, i.e. it does not satisfy the semigroup property.

Things would be ok if $Du=0$ or if $B(t)=B$ (though this is unlikely).